# update statement from different table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, multiple-tables

So I have been searching through other questions that were similar but I can't seem to get it to process. I keep getting the error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.` I know i have get my 2 tables to somewhere in my where clause but I am struggling.

***Tables***

**Price_list**

```
 brand_id (null)
 upc (populated)
```

**upc_list**

```
brand_id (populated)
upc (popualted)
```

SQL to pull list of null brand_ids

```
SELECT DISTINCT ul.brand_id
FROM price_list pl,
  upc_list ul
WHERE ul.upc     = pl.upc
AND ul.upc_type  = 'p'
AND pl.brand_id IS NULL ;
```

My Update Query:

```
  UPDATE pricelist
  SET pl.brand_id =
    (SELECT DISTINCT ul.brand_id
    FROM pricelist,
      upc_list
    WHERE ul.upc     =pl.upc
    AND ul.upc_type  = 'I'
    AND pl.brand_id IS NULL
    )
```

where (not sure what to enter. with or without it, it still gives the error above)

please help

Comment: `=` in `SET` is supposed to receive only one row.. Now your `SELECT` query returns more than one row.. Hence the error. You're perhaps looking for [correlated update](http://psoug.org/snippet/UPDATE-Correlated-Update_602.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *Correlated* *Update* Query.

Note that I added `ROWNUM <= 1` to always make the `subquery` to return one `brand_id` when there exists more than one for a `upc` match.

```
UPDATE pricelist pl
SET pl.brand_id =
  (
   SELECT ul.brand_id
   FROM upc_list ul
   WHERE ul.upc   = pl.upc
     AND ul.upc_type  = 'I'
     AND ROWNUM <= 1
  )
WHERE pl.brand_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Request you to display the result of the query to help you further.

The following query would pull NULL brand ids for upc_type='I' for which the update statement is executed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ul.brand_id
FROM pricelist,
  upc_list
WHERE ul.upc     =pl.upc
AND ul.upc_type  = 'I'
AND pl.brand_id IS NULL
```

Thanks & Regards,
Harsh